# Is Stack Mythology in any danger?

Tags: discussion

I notice a distinct lack of questions being asked, but I think this forum has enormous value.

It's pretty much a given that less people are interested in pre-industrial mythology these days than in, say, movies or genre fiction, and that should be taken into consideration.

I don't believe the relative lack of activity is a reflection of the usefulness or relevance of Stack Mythology, just that it has a more rarefied audience.

Answer (score 6):

The [*current* policy on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) is:

> - When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.
> - If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.
>
> Is your site in between these two categories? You don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site might be, you have a home here in the SE network. Spoiler alert: As of this post, no site which is currently active is at risk of being shut down.

Even though I'd certainly welcome more questions, I think it's safe to say that there's no reason for concern. We do consistently (albeit a bit slowly) produce helpful content, and the moderation workload is minimal<sup>1</sup>. There's certainly room for improvement in all aspects of the site, but, no, we aren't in danger of getting closed.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Our average flag handling time this quarter is ~12 hours. This doesn't accurately reflect the workload, though, as very few of our flags require quick responses (as do - for example - spam/abusive flags).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Well, were in public beta. So we're not in danger.

At one point, we were barely going with about 250-300 visitors per day, about 50 from our actual users.

Now, were at around 1000, a miracle I don't even know how it happened.

I mean, just look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators .

So, we won't get deleted, but keep never stop asking questions! (Sorry I've been a little busy ...)